# Manifest Problems

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-cardview

I have a tiny problem with my Manifest errors. I had a add_contact class and I add a CardView to my layout .I wanna make my add_contact and show_contact for all apis upper than 14... my debuger errors that I write in below: plz help me.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your dependencies from your `build.gradle`?  Hard to say without more information, but It looks like all of your support libraries aren't using the same versions.  The error is saying you have both 26.0.0-alpha1 as well as 25.3.1 for your CardView.  As of right now, 26.0.2 is the latest release.  I would recommended using that for all of your support dependencies.

Comment: I could fix it.(by changing the number of CardView Version to 26.+)

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
```

}